# Excel vba to autofill formulae from a column to last column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I do have a macro which adds formula in N2 cell and autofill it till last row in sheet.

```
Sub Formulae_to_find_EachFeatureCount()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(C2,R1C,C1,RC7)"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
   ' Range("N2:N10").Select
End Sub
```

I could also find last column (column name and number) with below code:

```
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
     'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Columns.
    LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    LastCol = Replace(Cells(1, LastColumn).Address(False, False), "1", "")
```

Now I want to autofill formulae from N column to last (used) column.

Comment: loop through the columns and fill the 1st cell and then in the end use autofill in one go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub Formulae_to_find_EachFeatureCount()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(C2,R1C,C1,RC7)"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("N1:N" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:" & lastcol & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

***NOTE:*** However using **SELECT** should be avoided.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for. Just changed N1 to N2 else it is replacing all my headers which were used in formulas. Sometimes formulae are not calculated correctly, to update them, shall I switch between Calculations options>

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad - Yeah, overlooked `N1`. But need details on `not calculated correctly`. Is formula being copied incorrectly or is it the result of the formulas?

Comment: Formulae are copied correctly but sometimes issues comes 1. when calculation gets interrupted as we click on any cell. 2. When there are thousands or lakhs of formulae are there.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad - Try `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` adding in the beginning of code and then set them TRUE at the ned.

Comment: I will try. Thank you!